# How to get all files modified in a certain time window?

Tags: python, python-os

I want to get all files modified/created in the last 1 hour with Python. I tried this code but it's only getting the last file which was created:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('c://*')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

If I created 10 files it shows only last one. How to get ***all*** files created in the last 1 hour?

Comment: The `max()` function returns a single value. That is what it is supposed to do. If you want several files then your code needs to examine the value returned by `os.path.getctime()` for each file to see if it meets your criteria. So you need a loop that begins `for filename in list_of_files:`.

Comment: Can you show me with code ? how to do ?

Comment: You will need to **sort** the list of files using the same key, and then remove all those file in it that are outside the time interval (i.e. the last hour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do basically this:

- get the list of files
- get the time for each of them (also check `os.path.getmtime()` for updates)
- use `datetime` module to get a value to compare against (that 1h)
- compare

For that I've used a dictionary to both store paths and timestamps in a compact format. Then you can sort the dictionary by its values (`dict.values()`) (which is a float, timestamp) and by that you will get the latest files created within 1 hour that are *sorted*. (e.g. by `sorted(...)` function):

```py
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

hour_files = {
    key: val for key, val in {
        path: os.path.getctime(path)
        for path in glob.glob("./*")
    }.items()
    if datetime.fromtimestamp(val) >= datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
}
```

Alternatively, without the comprehension:

```py
files = glob.glob("./*")
times = {}
for path in files:
    times[path] = os.path.getctime(path)

hour_files = {}
for key, val in times.items():
    if datetime.fromtimestamp(val) < datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1):
        continue
    hour_files[key] = val
```

Or, perhaps your folder is just a mess and you have too many files. In that case, approach it incrementally:

```
hour_files = {}
for file in glob.glob("./*"):
    timestamp = os.path.getctime(file)
    if datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) < datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1):
        continue
    hour_files[file] = timestamp
```

Comment: and what print to get result ?

Comment: `print(hour_files)` with the mapping, `print(hour_files.keys())` or `print(list(hour_files))` for just paths. After the [`sorted()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/5994041) call, if you want to sort it, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution, shorter, that uses only the `os` package:

```
import os
directory = "/path/to/directory"
latest_file = os.popen(f"ls -t {directory}").read().split("\n")[0]
```

Comment: The OP already has a solution for the last file. They are asking for all files changed in the last hour